# "non-static method makeHands() cannot be referenced from a static context" What does this mean, and how do I avoid it?

Tags: java, static

When I try to run this program, I get the above quoted error. Making makeHands static ends only in disaster, and making main non-static does nothing. What do I do?

http://pastebin.com/XPDKK7XR

To save space, the code is at that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().new Deck().makeHands();
}
```

The explanation is a little convoluted but i will try to make it clearer.

Basically `Deck` is an `inner class` of the `Main` class. One feature of inner classes (if they aren't static as in this case) is the fact that instances can't exist without an instance of the outer class. Basically each instance of the `Deck` needs to have a  reference to an instance of the `Main` class and you can't create a `Deck` instance if you don't have a `Main` instance available.

The syntax I pasted above will make sure that the proper instances exist: first it will create a Main instance and after that it will create a Deck instance pointing to the Main instance created before. Finally it will call the non static method `makeHands()`.

The more comprehensive explanation is available here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Correct... just to add.... the code posted tries to use `Deck.makeHands()`. You cannot call a instance (non-static) method using the class reference. The method needs to run on a object of the class... hence the need for new Deck() etc. as Toader mentions

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely need it, look back to see why you need to use a static variable. The limitation of using static variables from a static context alone is in place for a reason.

If it is absolutely necessary for you to do this, instantiate a new object of the class inside the non-static function and perform the required operation.